# How to change font style for part of a tkinter label

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, label, styling

I'm wondering how I can change the font of a Python Tkinter label widget so that half the displayed text is bold and half is not without having to use two labels. The text for the widget is assigned prior to the label actually being created and stored in a variable so I need some kind of flag presumably to tell it how much of the string should be bold. I don't it is possible but suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing you can do with the label widget -- it only supports a single font and single color for the entire label. However, you can easily substitute a canvas or text widget anywhere you need this feature. There's no reason why you can't use a text widget that is one line tall and a dozen or so characters wide.

Comment: Or you could just compose a widget from two labels... Text widget will have different appearance, and it can't be shrunk to the size of a label

Comment: @BłażejMichalik: that is not true. You can get the exact same appearance with a Text widget as with a label, and a text widget can be shrunk as small as you like.

Comment: Maybe you can get the same appearance through extensive configuration, but you won't be able to shirnk it to the same size, since `tkinter.Text` is a composed widget, and every level of it's composition ads a margin inside of it. Configuring a text widget to `width=1, height=1` doesn't makes it as small as a label with the same configuration. At least width-wise. Also, you would need to reconfigure it to be disabled and unselectable.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik: What do you mean "tkinter.Text is a composed widget"? That makes absolutely no sense. It's not composed, it's a core tk widget. It has exactly one border and one highlight ring, just like the label. Sure, you have to enable and disable it, and it takes two or three configuration options to get an identical look, but that's hardly "extensive configuration". With two lines of code I can give you a text widget that looks absolutely identical in every way to a label.

Comment: I've just created both `Text` and `Label` with width and height set to 1 and inserted the same text into both. On my environment (GNOME) the `Text` widget shows one letter, while label shows two. `tkinter.Text` has more layers to it than `Label`, even if it is a core widget.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an out-of-the-box method for changing the font within a label, but you could make a custom label type to handle it, for example:

```
def customLabel(parent, row, column, bold, standard):
    cLabelFrame = Frame(parent)
    cLabelFrame.grid(row=row, column=column)
    Label(cLabelFrame, text=bold, font=('bold').grid(column=0)
    Label(cLabelFrame, text=standard).grid(column=1)
```

Where the arguments: `parent` is the containing frame, `bold` is your bold text, and `standard` is the regular text. You'd have to figure out where to split your original string and assign it to the `bold` and `standard` args.